# Dynamic button create in the mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some code clarification. I have a project that in MVC. When view loaded in the web application  and then need to be create input button dynamically in the view page. And also how they merge in the controller. I don't have any idea about this I checked many webs but does not have any answer for this.

How to create button dynamically when view load in the web?

Comment: Please improve the layout/casing of your question. Also improve your problem description.

Comment: Probably need to clarify your use case. "When view load" - well, in that case you can just use Razor as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866622/creating-buttons-dynamically-in-mvc-5). Another technique is to just hide the markup and use javascript to .hide()/.show() as needed. Otherwise use js to insert into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create button after the page loads then you have to use javascript to create the html and then add that to the page.

For example:

```
$(document).append(
  $("input")
  .attr("type", "button")
  .click(function(){
    doSomething()
  ))
);
```

You can find the detail of the answer here: [Inject html using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932131/inject-html-using-javascript)